# How to get the level of volume setted for each media

Tags: android, volume

Here is the UI of each controller which i want to set

**Q** How to get the level of volume setted for each media?

[image]

Regrads mann

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get various stream volume levels using `getStreamVolume` from the `AudioManager`.

For example:

```
int musicVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Available streams copied from the Android docs: [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

```
STREAM_ALARM             The audio stream for alarms
STREAM_DTMF              The audio stream for DTMF Tones
STREAM_MUSIC             The audio stream for music playback
STREAM_NOTIFICATION      The audio stream for notifications
STREAM_RING              The audio stream for the phone ring
STREAM_SYSTEM            The audio stream for system sounds
STREAM_VOICE_CALL        The audio stream for phone calls
USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE  Suggests using the default stream type.
```

Comment: audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(?));  what should i write here for getting the desired details

Comment: @mnn An id of one of the available streams, eg. `STREAM_MUSIC` or `STREAM_RING`. See answer edit for details.